# Vim: goto function definition

Tags: vim

I know the way to go to the function declaration (using ctags + `Ctrl + ]`). But what if I want not to go to the function *declaration*, but to the function *definition* instead.

For example:

```
// foo.c
#include "foo.h"

...
if (x > 3) foo_function(x);
...

void foo_function(int x) {
    ...
}
```

and

```
// foo.h
void foo_function(int x);
```

Then `Ctrl + ]` opens `foo.h` and points to the `void foo_function(int x);` line. I want to go to the `foo.c` to the `foo_function` definition. I have `taglist` installed, but don't want to open the taglist window every time I just want to jump to the function definition under cursor. Is there a way to do this with a keymap?

Thanks.

Comment: You are confusing the terms *declaration* and *definition*. I edited your question to fix that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get ctags in vim to go to definition, not declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054701/get-ctags-in-vim-to-go-to-definition-not-declaration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> to get a picklist first

Answer (score 1):

If you add the mappings suggested in `:help cscope-suggestions`, then you can use `^- g` (control minus, then g -- nicely enough, even though the mappings were defined with `<C-_>`, vim lets you skip the shift key) to find the definition of the function under the cursor.

You could of course use any key mappings; I've seen control+`\` as the default mapping in a cscope plugin.

Answer (score 1):

As similar question was already asked on stack overflow:

[Get ctags in vim to go to definition, not declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054701/get-ctags-in-vim-to-go-to-definition-not-declaration)

You may find answers there helpful.